# Wrap word at / with css within a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a row that looks something like
    
       word
       hi Someword/AnotherWord/LastWord

I would like to use css to break hi Someword/AnotherWord/LastWord at the "/" symbol

Right now my css looks something like:

```
tbody td {
  padding: 11px 12px;
  word-break: normal;
 }
```

the word breaks like this:

```
hi
Someword/AnotherWord
/LastWord
```

Right now Someword/AnotherWord are flowing outside of the table cell. How do I get it to break so it looks something like

```
  hi
  Someword
  /AnotherWord
  /LastWord
```

I have tried :

word-wrap: break-word;

word-break: break-all;

which end up breaking in the middle of the words. Is there a way to break at the "/" only?

Comment: CSS alone can't do that. It has no way of knowing what the content of the elements are. Probably will need JavaScript.

Comment: Where does "someword" come from? Handcoded or inserted with javascript? php?

Comment: Do you have any control over the content? Is a <br/> not going to work?

Comment: And this isn't practical for you to use today, but keep an eye on the developing CSS3 property "line-break" http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#line-breaking

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in CSS. There is no provision for specifying a forced or optional line break after a character, without turning that character to an element (or the first or last character of an element). Generally, CSS works on elements, not characters.

Whether browsers automatically treat a “/” as allowing a line break before or after it depends on the browser. In practice, some browsers treat it as allowing a break *after* it (which is meaningful in many contexts), but hardly before it.

There are different ways to allow or force line breaks in HTML, possibly with the aid of CSS. If you cannot directly modify the HTML, you would then need to use client-side JavaScript (in order to add elements).